# Photo gallery in android coding clarification?

Tags: android

i am new to the android platform, can anyone explain the below code: i go through the photo gallery but in this code i was stuck

source code:

http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/writing-image-picker-using-intent-in-android

already switch case  is receiving the command from SELECT_PHOTO: ,

then why we are using if case?

what will be in `(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) ;`

what this will do?
`super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);`

please explain step by step , it will great helpful for me to understand.
thanks in advance

prg coding:

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
  imageReturnedIntent) { 
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

 switch(requestCode) { 

 case SELECT_PHOTO:
 if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
 {

 try {

 final Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

 final InputStream imageStream = 
 getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);

 final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

 imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);

 } 

 catch (FileNotFoundException e)

 {
 e.printStackTrace();
```

Answer (score 0):

The if clause is used to ensure that the activity has returned a correct result and has not failed.
If you didn't use the if, you could decode an image that hasn't been selected yet(so it doesn't exist in your context), for example.

Comment: protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

this code result?